# Postgis + Qgis - filtered row access - problem on insert and update new points

Tags: postgresql, postgis, rules, qgis, policy

I have this problem:

PostGis Server with a table: Table_Points_of_all_works
table has a field "ID_WORK" so I can filter points for only one work.

with different groups (a group for each work).
Each group can access to the only work related, and view, insert, delete rows (related to their only ID_Work)

To do this I created groups and policies:

```
CREATE POLICY policy_for_this_groupofWork
ON public."Table_Points_of_all_works"
AS PERMISSIVE
FOR ALL
TO "GroupWork12"
USING ("ID_WORK"=12)
WITH CHECK ("ID_WORK"=12);
```

Viewing the table of points in QGIS works: only points of related work are seen.
But when I insert new points and giving in the field ID_WORK correct work (12 in this case), I receive an error while updating SQL:

*"Could not commit changes to layer Table_Points_of_all_works
Errors: ERROR: 1 feature(s) not added - provider doesn't support adding features."*

If I do the same thing with admin users (postgres) all works fine.

Anyone can help me?

thanks in advance,
Filippo